# Website JS not reacting to X button (Closed)

Tags: javascript, html, css, displaytag

I'm making a website where I want a window that pops up and when I click on the X it closes by making its css a display:none;
This is my HTML:

```
<div id="PortOverlay"></div>
<div id="PortContainer">
   <div id="poCross">X</div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#PortOverlay {width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;position:fixed;z-index:10;background-color:#222;opacity:0.4;display:block;}
#PortContainer {width:800px;height:auto;min-height:800px;position:fixed;margin:18px auto;background:#FFF;border-radius:10px;box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #888;}
#PortContainer > div#poCross {width:auto;height:auto;font-family:arial;font-weight:bolder;font-family:16px;margin:15px;}
#PortContainer > div#poContent {}
```

This is my JS:

```
var poCross, PortContainer, PortOverlay;
function poClose(){
poCross = document.getElementById('poCross');
PortContainer = document.getElementById('PortContainer');
PortOverlay = document.getElementById('PortOverlay');
if (poCross.click()) {
    PortContainer.style.display = "none";
    PortOverlay.style.display = "none";
    alert('test'); // Alert included for testing //
   }
}
```

I've even included an alert to test if it was just a CSS problem but this doesn't react also.
Thanks for the help.
(I'm Dutch and 15 so sorry for wrong grammar orso )

Comment: `poCross.onclick=function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have only runs when the page is loaded. At that time, your DOM element exists, but `click()` will always return false, and the code will never be evaluated again.

What you want is an `onClick` event handler. Event handlers run *when the event occurs*, not when the code is loaded for the first time.

Comment: Thanks, uses an onclick in my HTML. I'm pretty new to JS so I don't know a lot of it. But it works know!

Comment: Ok, then there wasn't enough context around the JS to know how it was connected in, I guess. You might want to close the question now.

Comment: Didn't put a z-index in the CSS of #PortContent thats why the button didn't respond. Cause the was a layer above it